# Memory warning in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have the one webview which load the this url 
https://sketchfab.com/models/9fb581d7cb414e0fbec4108099a73619/embed.

After loading this url my web view start showing the memory warning and after some time it crash. I am using the arc in my application
Here is my code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

NSURL *sUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/embed",m_Data.m_sModelUrl]];
NSMutableURLRequest *sRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sUrl];
[sRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

[m_webView loadRequest:sRequest];

}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: can you post some error and crash details.

Comment: It is just show the Received memory warning and after some time the app  crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `autoreleasepool` to solve memory warning.

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    NSURL *sUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/embed",m_Data.m_sModelUrl]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *sRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sUrl];
    [sRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
}
[m_webView loadRequest:sRequest];
```

Comment: ok, try with put this line in auto release pool insted outside it, [m_webView loadRequest:sRequest];
And restart your device once if possible.

Comment: I put the [m_webView loadRequest:sRequest]; in autorelease pool.But it is not working.Ca you pleas make a sample code of it